# unable to pass azurerm_subnet resource group through -var-file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to run terraform plan -var-file -out and then apply the plan but I get the following error.

Here's my **main.tf**, **variable.tf** and networking.tfvars file below:

```
###### Resource Group ##############
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroupname" {
  name     = "${var.resourcegrouprefix}-RG"
  location = "${var.location}"
}

###### VNET ##############
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "${var.vnet-prefix}-vnet"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.location}"
  address_space       = "${var.vnetcidr}"
}
# address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/20"]

###### Subnets ##############
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "${var.subnet1-prefix}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
  address_space       = "${var.subnet1cidr}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "${var.subnet2-prefix}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
  address_space       = "${var.subnet2cidr}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet3" {
  name                 = "${var.subnet3-prefix}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
  address_space       = "${var.subnet3cidr}"
```

**Variables File**

```
variable "resourcegrouprefix" {
  description = "The prefix used for all resources in VNET RG"
  default = ""
}

variable "vnet-prefix" {
  description = "The prefix used for VNET resource"
  default = ""
}

variable "vnetcidr" {
  default = ""
}

variable "subnet1cidr" {
  default = ""
}

variable "subnet2cidr" {
  default = ""
}
variable "subnet3cidr" {
  default = ""
}
```

**Networking.tfvars**

```
resourcegrouprefix = "networking"
vnet-prefix = "networking"
vnetcidr = "10.0.0.0/20"
subnet1-prefix = "untrust"
subnet2-prefix = "trust"
subnet3-prefix = "mgmt"
subnet1cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
subnet2cidr = "10.0.1.0/24"
subnet3cidr = "10.0.2.0/24"
```

Command that I'm trying to execute:

```
terraform plan -var-file="networking.tfvars" -out="networkingplan.out"
```

Error message:

> azurerm_subnet.subnet1: "address_prefix": required field is not set
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet1: : invalid or unknown key: address_space
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet2: "address_prefix": required field is not set
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet2: : invalid or unknown key: address_space
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet3: "address_prefix": required field is not set
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet3: : invalid or unknown key: address_space
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet4: "address_prefix": required field is not set
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet4: : invalid or unknown key: address_space
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet5: "address_prefix": required field is not set
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet5: : invalid or unknown key: address_space
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet6: "address_prefix": required field is not set
>   azurerm_subnet.subnet6: : invalid or unknown key: address_space
>   azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: address_space: should be a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error message

```
   ###### Resource Group ##############
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroupname" {
      name     = "${var.resourcegrouprefix}-RG"
      location = "${var.location}"
    }

    ###### VNET ##############
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
      name                = "${var.vnet-prefix}-vnet"
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
      location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.location}"
      address_space       = ["${var.vnetcidr}"]
    }
    # address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/20"]

    ###### Subnets ##############
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
      name                 = "${var.subnet1-prefix}"
      virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
      address_prefix      = "${var.subnet1cidr}"
    }

    resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
      name                 = "${var.subnet2-prefix}"
      virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
      address_prefix     = "${var.subnet2cidr}"
    }

    resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet3" {
      name                 = "${var.subnet3-prefix}"
      virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
      resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroupname.name}"
      address_prefix    = "${var.subnet3cidr}"
    }
```